# OBLMTLLoader name of the mesh empty

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a sort of bug I can't explain when I use OBJMTLLoader instead of OBJLoader.
My obj file contains groups that are load by both loaders in different children mesh.

I have in the two case as a children of the scene a THREE.Object3D with the same number of children: 1837.
However, when I display this object in js console and I inspect it:

- for the one loads with OBJLoader the first children has got the id 12 and the id increases of one for each new mesh and finish with the id 1848. That makes sense.
- With the same object loads with OBJMTLLoader, some id are missing, in fact the first children has 13 as id and the last children has a id equals to 5521. And for instance here are the id of the 5 first children : 13 16 19 22 25

This may not be a problem but here is the tricky par of the story, to the aim of my project I use the raycaster in order to change the color of a selected mesh (by clicking on it). I also display the name of the selected mesh:

- With OBJLoader when I use the raycaster I modify the color of the mesh and I display the name without any problem.
- But with OBJMTLLoader I change the color of the selected mesh without any trouble, however the name of the mesh is nothing (without any character).

The funny think is that every mesh has a name well imported in the two cases.

The only thing that is strange is when I display the id of the selected mesh in the two cases with OBJLoader I can find in my object display in js console this id in the list of mesh and the name correspond but with OBJMTLLoader the id that I get is nowhere in the Object3D...

Is anybody got an idea where the problem can be ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

UPDATE :

I have found a part of the solution but still there is something strange, here is an example of the structure of my 3D model when I import it with THREE.OBJMTLLoader :

```
THREE.Group
     [...]
     children : Array[1837]
                0 : THREE.Object3D
                        [...]
                        name : "the name of the part"
                        children : Array[2]
                                      0: THREE.Mesh
                                               name : ""
                                               children : Array[0]
                                               [...]
                                      1: THREE.Mesh 
                                                [...]
                          [...]
                 1 : THREE.Object3D
                 [...]
```

In fact the raycaster compute the intersection with the THREE.Mesh and the name is store at the level n-1 from this mesh. That is why I have no name when I try to display it.
However why with OBJLoader my level n-1 does not exist for the same model 3D load ? In fact with OBJLoader the structure of the object is :

```
THREE.Group
    [...]
    children : Array[1837]
                0 : THREE.Mesh
                        [...]
                        name : "the name of the part"
                        children : Array[0]
                        [...]
                1 : THREE.Mesh
                [...]
```

Comment: so are you saying you have a mesh created in blender,max etc then when you import some have id's and some dont?

Comment: I have updated my question.
I think my mesh comes from blender and it is an .obj file with texture store in a .mtl file. 
The problem of the id came from the fact that I didn't see the new level created by OBJMTLLoader in the structure of my 3D object as explained in the update I published in my post.

Comment: I think it is how the obj is created , I thought child meshes of meshes dont have a name unless you assign one manually, say i have a character mesh, that mesh is like a container for all the vertices faces etc  than im in edit mode and start adding other objects inside the mesh, these im sure will be nameless...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when `OBJLoader` reads a `.obj` file, it creates a `THREE.Object3D` and for each group of the `.obj`, it creates a `THREE.Mesh` and adds it to the `Object3D`, ignoring the `usemtl` in your `.obj`. You'll have one `THREE.Mesh` per groups in your `.obj` with the correct name, and it's cool.

`OBJMTLLoader`, however, doesn't ignore the `usemtl`. And since a `Mesh` is bound with a `Geometry` and a `Material`, if you change the `Material`, you have to create another `Mesh`. So when it sees new groups, it will create an `Object3D` with the correct name, and this `Object3D`'s children will be the parts with different materials.

If you want to get the name of the *real mesh*, you probably want to do something like `intersect.object.parent.name`.